# Dijkstra's Algorithm direction issue

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, postgis-2.0, dijkstra

I am trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm, my query is working fine if I set direction parameter to false. I have to consider the direction of travel while calculating route from point A to point B. This algorithm determines the direction by the order of the coordinates in the linestring, this is where I am facing problem. If I am traveling from north to south and the linestring coordinates of that route are digitized from south to north then the algorithm is not returning the correct route. I am using geometry length as cost and reverse_cost.

So, my question is how can I solve this problem? I have another column in my table containing Boolean value if the road is one way or not, can I use this column somehow to find the correct route?

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem, it sounds like you need to implement some sort of priority queue for your nodes.  I am very unfamiliar with postgresql, but the concept you are going for is very similar to an A* path finding algorithm in which each node is given a heuristic value (distance from start node to end node) and cost value called g(the cost of traveling from the current node)  Adding these two values together gives you what we call an f value.  With these nodes added to a priority queue just pop the node with the lowest f value to get the direction and next node.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, the problem has been resolved now, I was using incorrect values of reverse_cost for directed roads. Thanks